# IE 11 Request.Browser.ActiveXControls returns false

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I've got a problem with IE 11 and ASP.net. Checking:

> `Request.Browser.ActiveXControls`

returns **false** and `Request.Browser` returns `Mozilla`.

How to workaround this issue?

What about using `headers["User-Agent"].Contains("Trident")`?

Comment: You are not supposed to. They are doing it so that you don't use it for whatever you use it.

Comment: It's also a Developer Preview. Things may or may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple factors here. First, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/24/10451776.aspx and more specifically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx -- the IE team made it so checking for the ActiveXObject in the DOM using JavaScript will fail in IE11 mode.

Now, you probably also have outdated browser definition files on your server that lead ASP.NET to incorrectly conclude (via the UA sniffing alone) that IE11 doesn't support ActiveX (which is only partially true). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: It seems that even with updated browser definition files (e.g. .NET Framework 4.5, or [hotfix KB2836939](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us)) that the `Request.Browser.ActiveXControls` still returns **false**. Changing the *"browser mode"* (i.e. the user agent string) to IE10, it works correctly. What is missing is a supported way for the *server* to detect if the client supports ActiveX.